# mssql_select_db isn't working properly

Tags: php, sql-server

```
// NO PROBLEM WITH IT
$dbhandle = mssql_connect(TB_DB_SERVER, TB_DB_USERID, TB_DB_PASSWORD) or die("Database connection error.");
$imageDBhandle = mssql_connect(TB_IMAGE_SERVER, TB_IMAGE_USERID, TB_IMAGE_PASSWORD) or die("Database connection error.");

// THIS WORKS FINE TOO

mssql_select_db("database", $dbhandle);
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = mssql_query($sql_query, $dbhandle); 

// THIS COMPLAINS - message: Invalid object name 'table2'

mssql_select_db("anotherDatabase", $imageDBhandle );
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table2";
$result = mssql_query($sql_query, $imageDBhandle );
```

mssql_connect and mssql_select_db never complains when executing the code. However, the second code seems like having an weird issue. Why the second part gives me an error?

Comment: @KingCrunch This isn't MySQL - it's MS-SQL - the only option is PDO, Raccoon - Check for errors from the queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "THIS COMPLAINS"? What line? There is nothing in your code with the name "mfProd", please show us the relevant code.

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to change that 'mfProd' thingy. It's an actual name of the database table I'm trying to access.  I will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my user id was not set to the owner of the DB I've been trying to access... :(  but still have no clue what err msg means... Anyway, it's solved.